# CloseOptionsMenu doesn't work?

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I only want to display the optionsMenu in a particular tab using the following code.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide fragments for each of the
     * three primary sections of the app. We use a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter}
     * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will display the three primary sections of the app, one at a
     * time.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    private int currentPage = 0;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//      this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
        // of the app.
        mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Specify that the Home/Up button should not be enabled, since there is no hierarchical
        // parent.
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        closeOptionsMenu();

        // Specify that we will be displaying tabs in the action bar.
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener for when the
        // user swipes between sections.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // When swiping between different app sections, select the corresponding tab.
                // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the
                // Tab.
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                currentPage = position;
                if (position == 2) {
                    openOptionsMenu();
                }
                else
                    closeOptionsMenu();
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
            // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
            // listener for when this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { //this method is used for adding menu items to the Activity
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the primary
     * sections of the app.
     */
    public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch (i) {
                default:
                    // The other sections of the app are dummy placeholders.
                    Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    return fragment;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Section " + (position + 1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A fragment that launches other parts of the demo application.
     */
    public static class LaunchpadSectionFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_launchpad, container, false);

            // Demonstration of a collection-browsing activity.
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.demo_collection_button)
                    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CollectionDemoActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });

            // Demonstration of navigating to external activities.
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.demo_external_activity)
                    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Create an intent that asks the user to pick a photo, but using
                            // FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET, ensures that relaunching
                            // the application from the device home screen does not return
                            // to the external activity.
                            Intent externalActivityIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                            externalActivityIntent.setType("image/*");
                            externalActivityIntent.addFlags(
                                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
                            startActivity(externalActivityIntent);
                        }
                    });

            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_dummy, container, false);
            Bundle args = getArguments();
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
                    getString(R.string.dummy_section_text, args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. The optionsMenu are still there no matter which fragment is activated.
(The currentPage in the code is always changed when switching tabs.)

[image: Options Menu]

Comment: position==2 means you are trying your code at page no 3 in actual !

Comment: Yes, I have three tabbed fragments. I want the optionsMenu appears in the third fragment, not the other two. Thanks

Comment: did you tried openOptionsMenu(); in onCreate() just for testing that its working or not ?

Comment: I tried closeOptionsMenu in onCreate(), and the optionsMenu is still there... weird.

Comment: please post some more code !

Comment: Added more code. I am just using the Tab Fragment template provided by developer.android.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you want to have an options menu in a particular tab fragment is not creating the options menu in the activity then hide/show it.

Instead of calling onCreateOptionsMenu() inside the Activity, call onCreateOptionsMenu() inside a fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }
```

and don't forget to add this

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
```

to the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right.Each of your fragment should have enabled [setHasOptionsMenu(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu%28boolean%29), if you want to have unique or action items at all per each.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the app. You can see there is an optionsMenu below the tabs with two arrow buttons. I want to dismiss/hide it in STORE and LOCATION tab, and display/show it in SOCIAL tab. But the closeOptionsMenu() does not work at all. And even I put setHasOptionsMenu(false) in STORE and LOCATION fragments, the optionsMenu is still there.

Comment: I said try it with setHasOptionsMenu(true). Did you try that?

Comment: Well, your answer is good, but you didn't see where the problem is. Thus I would vote you but not consider as the answer. Thanks a lot.