# Android - onCreateOptionsMenu - Can't disable MenuItem from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-menu, oncreateoptionsmenu

I'm trying to disable the MenuItem's in my navigationdrawer from my 
fragment, but it just wont work...

Fragment code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.waiting_for_terminal, container, false);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_drawer, menu);

        menu.findItem(R.id.nav_amount).setEnabled(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.nav_return).setEnabled(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.nav_about).setEnabled(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.nav_settings).setEnabled(false);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

I can call getTitle() for the MenuItems, and it will return correct value. But for some reason setEnabled(), setTitle(), setVisible() etc. does not work, the value stays the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try This:

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    oldDescription= ActivityConstantUtils.sBlogDescriprtion;
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_act_add_section, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_preview);
    item.setIcon(null);
    item.setTitle("");
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: by using this you can hide some item and show other from menu.

Comment: Paste here your Fragment Activity.

Answer (score 4):

to disable menuitem in fragment use it with fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(false);
}
```

Remove onCreateOptionsMenu() inside the Activity,and use inside a fragment as:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }
```

Comment: check it http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)

Comment: you have to remove it from activity, and i'll give you links related to you problem to get them work for you

Comment: check some problems which is being faced by developer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498534/hide-menuitem-in-some-fragments  , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825297/closeoptionsmenu-doesnt-work  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to disable that Home Button on the AppBar which toggles the NavigationDrawer.

The best way i can think of doing that is:

In Method onOptionItemSelected:

```
protected onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
   if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
    {
            // do anything you want here
    }
}
```

This will help you override that Home Button.

More over if you want to replace that Hamburger Icon with an Default Arrow Icon, you can use

```
mNavigationDrawer.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

Additionally if you want to disable the drawer Swipe Functionality also,
you can use

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

Hope it Helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Omg, my bad...

It was MenuItems in the NavigationView I wanted to disable...

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_amount).setEnabled(false);
```

Thanks for the help though :)